# How do the order of quantifiers affect the truth of a statement?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am just being introduced to quantifiers in logic and my lecturer was going through the following two statements. The question is to determine which, if any, is/are true.

1. $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(\exists y \in \mathbb{R})[x + y = 0]$
2. $(\exists x \in \mathbb{R})(\forall y \in \mathbb{R})[x + y = 0]$

Clearly, the first statement is true; we can just let $y = -x$. However, my lecturer says that the second statement is false. I cannot wrap my head around why that is the case. If we can take $y = -x$ in the first, why can we not do the same for the second i.e. let $x = -y$? In fact, how is the second statement any different from the first?

Any intuitive explanations/examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the second one you have to find an $x$ such that, **with every possible** value for $y$ we have $x+y=0$. If $x=0$, only $y=0$ will do. With $x \ne 0$ we have that for $y=x$ the equation $x+y=0$ gives $2x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you translate the sentences into English, you can see the differences between them.

The first sentence says "Every real number has an additive inverse."  That is for every real number $x$, there is  real number $y$ such that $x+y=0$.  As you say, this is clearly true since we can take $y:=-x$.

By contrast, the second sentence says "There is a real number such that all real numbers are its additive inverse."  That is, first we choose the value of $x$, and then every value of $y$ must then satisfy $x+y=0$.  So your lecturer is right; once we specify the value of $x$ (which we have to do first since it is the first quantified variable in the expression), there is only one additive inverse of $x$ and so any other real number would not satisfy the equation.

Comment: Yes! As Mauro has so kindly pointed out as a comment. I feel like I have wasted everyone's time by posting this. Thank you for your answer nonetheless!

Comment: @EthanMark We've all been there!  ^_^ Any question whose answer helps you is a good question.

Comment: If you have learned something, then it is not a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

The second one is false because **there is no real number $x$ such that its addition with all real numbers results in $0$.** You can take $y=x^2+1$ for each $x$ and observe that $$x+y=x^2+x+1\ne 0$$